# macOS上でのPythonとkivyを用いたGUIについて

Tags: python, python3, macos, kivy

---

開発・実行環境：macOS High Sierra
Python3.5
Kivy1.10

macOS上でPythonとKivyを使って簡単なGUIを作ってみたのですが、
Buttonをクリックした際の挙動がタッチ向けになっているのが不便で困っています。
具体的に言うと、単純なクリックではボタンが押せず、右クリックで赤いカーソル(仮想的なタッチポイント？)の場所をButtonの上に移動してクリックをしないといけません。
Buttonのハンドラーにはon_pressで関数をセットしています(これはセットしてもしなくても挙動には関係はないですが)

これはkivyの仕様なのでしょうか？
また、これを一般的なボタンクリックの挙動に変更する方法がありましたらお教えいただけるとありがたいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。